# Exclude package from being pulled in from an external jar in maven assembly

Tags: maven, slf4j

We had a bug whereby our logger stopped doing anything.  In the end, we tracked it down to an external dependency, say:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bob</groupId>
        <artifactId>alice</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

which has it's own slf4j implementation.  I had changed our pom so this dependency was listed first, which is what triggered the bug.  Moving the dependency back to being listed last fixed the issue (so that the usual log4j implementation was used).

This seems like a very fragile fix.  The "correct" fix would seem to be to get the maven assembly plugin to exclude importing, from the alice.jar file, any file in the org.slf4j package.  We tried adding something to our custom assembly xml file, like:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>com.bob:alice:org/slf4j/*</exclude>
```

However, this didn't work.  The best I could do was:

```
               <exclude>org/slf4j/*</exclude>
```

But this excludes *all* copies of that package, which obviously breaks everything.

What is the correct way to do this exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.bob</groupId>
        <artifactId>alice</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>    
</dependency>
```

And then add the dependency `slf4j` like this : (You can modify the version of the `slf4j`)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No, sorry, I should be more clear!  The alice artifact does _not_ pull in the slf4j as a dependency.  It contains it's own, custom, implementation.  So opening up the alice.jar file shows an org/slf4j directory, with a LoggerFactory.class etc.